# Satellite imagery comparison

Tags: imagery, satellite, comparison, world-imagery

Earlier in my searches I had come across this website which provided a fast switchback between all the map providers (Apple Maps, Google, Bing, OSM) where you had the chance to compare the satellite imagery between all the different providers. Unfortunately, this website escaped my browser history and now I can't find it anywhere.

I'm aware this sounds a little delusional but is there such a site that provided this opportunity? I'm aware of geofabrik.de's [comparison tool](https://tools.geofabrik.de/mc/#15/49.0094/8.3902&num=4&mt0=mapnik&mt1=geofabrik-basic-colour&mt2=mapnik-german&mt3=here-map) and it's similar to that but rather than side by side windows, this site was full screen.

Comment: I'm not aware of datafabrik's tool. Please provide a link.

Comment: @StuSmith Link provided with the last edit

Comment: This is not a full answer to my question or the original side-by-side comparison site I was looking for but it comes close... the link is provided below and it let's you switch between different mapping vendors;
https://satellites.pro/Cuba_map#B23.093923,-82.382583,19

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like flashearth.com which has been offline for years now.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/257459)